# (Android) Overlay one audio to another audio

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, android-audiomanager

suppose that I have a audio file(10s), and I also have another one(2s). What I want is to overlay the second one to the first one, for example: first file(10s): *1111111111* (where "1" stands for 1sec), Second file(2s): *22*. If I want to overlay the second file on first file on time-line 5s,6s: *1111221111*. How should i do? I have already search for some solution like: ffmpeg, but i want this can be done without using server. Thanks.

Comment: MultiThreading will help you

Answer (score 1):

[`amix`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#amix) filter is what you are looking for. It will mix/overlay the audios according to your need. Simply you can append a 4 sec silent audio using [`aevalsrc`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#aevalsrc) to the second audio and mix the result with first audio.

```
ffmpeg -i input_audio1 -i input_audio2 -filter_complex "
aevalsrc=0:d=4[s1];
[s1][1:a]concat=n=2:a=1:v=0[a2];
[0:a][a2]amix" -c:a libmp3lame output_audio
```

You can use appropriate audio codec according to you output audio format. Here I have used `libmp3lame` for a `mp3` and you can find all the codecs [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html). Also if you need to trim the audio to a specific length, you can use [`atrim`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#atrim) with `filter_complex` or `-t` option accordingly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: is it possible to add the silence using milliseconds instead of seconds? According to the documentation it looks it's not possible? Do you have a way to do it? Basically something like aevalsrc=0:d=0,5[s1];(e.g. half second)